# How to use callback function with Jeditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I attach a class to an element via javascript for styling purposes. When I do inline editing via jeditable the class disappears. I'd like to put it back in via a callback but it's not working. This is what I have:

```
$('.edit_area').editable('{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}', {
loadurl: '{% url 'load_for_editing' post.id %}',
submitdata : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : "{{ csrf_token }}"},
type: 'textarea',
cancel: 'Cancel',
submit: 'OK',
indicator: '<img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}images/loading.gif">',
tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
callback: function(value, settings) {
   $('pre').has('code').addClass("prettyprint");
   prettyPrint();
}
});
```

It doesn't work. I also tried a simple javscript alert to test and nothing came up for that either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm not very experienced with javascript.